# Is there a way to make VTDecompressionSession decode H264 when app in background mode?

Tags: video-toolbox

Is there a way to make `VTDecompressionSession` decode H264 when app in background mode?

Answer (score 0):

Check [UIApplication
beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623031-beginbackgroundtaskwithexpiratio), from my test it's only allow to run the process within 180 seconds after App into background mode.